# How to check data in db using fluent Nhibernate

Tags: asp.net, fluent-nhibernate

I'm new to fluent NHibernate  and I'm stuck with a problem I'm creating an app and I've  a login page in my app and How can I check that the entered name and password is exist in my db using fluent nhibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void CheckLogin(string username, string password)
{
    // assuming username is unique
    var users = DbSession.Query<User>()
        .Where(u => u.Name == username && u.PasswordHash == password)
        .List();

    if (users.Count == 0)
    {
        // invalid username or password
    }
    else
    {
        User loggingInUser = users[0];
        // do something with user
    }
}
```